# Throw javascript error when using the Kendo UI filterable function

Tags: filter, menu, kendo-ui

I am using the KendoUI Kendo UI v2015.1.408 version. I want to create a grid withe filter menu , but the javascript error "kendoFilterCell is not a function" is thrown. Below is my code ( Actually I just using one of the kendo UI example:

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
                { field: "name" },
                { field: "age" }
            ],
            filterable: {`enter code here`
                mode: "menu, row"
            },
            dataSource: [
                { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },


          { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: The code above is working just fine (if you remove the `enter code here`).  Can your error be elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have updated the Kenod UI version to latest version. Then this issue is fixed. However, another problem is occurred = [.. The drop down value is excess out of the drop down list....i don't know why ...